# How can I reload a script in IRB?

Tags: ruby, irb

I am writing a Ruby script for use in the Rails environment, but I chose to run it from irb because reloading the Rails console can be a pain. Now the wait time is much shorter from irb, but I'm bothered that I have to restart irb and require the script everytime I make a change. Is there a simpler way of reloading a script from irb?

I found a method in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463182/reload-rubygem-in-irb), but that only applies to gem files apparently. My require statement looks like this

```
 require "#{File.expand_path(__FILE__)}/../lib/query"
```

EDIT: Having tried `load` rather than `require`, I still couldn't get it to work. I can't get a stop on these errors.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > load "#{File.expand_path(__FILE__)}/../lib/query.rb"
LoadError: no such file to load -- /Users/newuser/Dropbox/Sites/rails/hacknyc/(irb)/../lib/query.rb
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

In irb, `File.expand_path(__FILE__)}` will just return `"#{path you ran irb from}/(irb)"`.  Which creates a path that doesn't actually exist.  Luckily all file paths are relative to where you ran irb anyway.  This means all you need is:

```
load "lib/query.rb"
```

If you want to use the `__FILE__` in an actual file, that's fine, but don't expect it to produce a valid path in irb.  Because an irb there is no "file" at all, so it cannot return valid path at all.

Also, `__FILE__` will work fine if used in a file loaded into irb via load or require.  Cause that's kinda what it's for.

Answer (score 43):

Instead of using `require`, try `load`. The former only loads a source file once, while the latter loads it every time you call it.

Comment: I tried load but it keeps complaining that it cannot find the file, and I did put the rb extension at the end of the line.

Comment: For reference, look at "Ruby Require VS Load VS Include VS Extend" -- http://ionrails.com/2009/09/19/ruby_require-vs-load-vs-include-vs-extend/

Answer (score 3):

according to [this link](http://blog.serendeputy.com/posts/how-to-reload-a-class-in-irb/) you need to load your file and do not forget the extention.

Here is a fancier version to use too at [this link number 2](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2009/03/27/irb-tip-load-files-faster) which could be helpful for you too.

You may want to try hashing out why your rails console isn't working for you though.

Comment: Rails console is simply too slow to load. I tried `load` but it keeps complaining that it cannot find the file, and I did put the rb extension at the end of the line.

Comment: if this file is inside of your lib directory, then it's loaded and you can/should be able to use it, unless it pukes up errors on starting.  To use it in another file, you just need to add `require NameOfModuleOrClass` (that is inside that query file), to one of the files in your rails app.

Answer (score 1):

I think `load` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried `load` but it keeps complaining that it cannot find the file, and I did put the rb extension at the end of the line.

Comment: Try putting the extension of the file