# Ruby version errors / crack/xml in irb

Tags: ruby, irb

Because of a bug with `Float#round` in Ruby 1.8.6, I was forced to upgrade to 1.9.3 and boy was that awful. After install, irb didn't work, complaining of a lack of `psych`. So I tried to install the gem, but it was angry that `libyaml` didn't exist, so I installed that. Not sure why they weren't included if they were so important.

Now when I use `require 'Location.rb'` (after having to specify that I actually do want to look in the current folder... using `$LOAD_PATH`), I get this error:

```
 LoadError: cannot load such file -- crack/xml
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ap-0.1.1/lib/ap.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /Users/tyre77/Dropbox/Aurora/GMap.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from (irb):3
from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

What does this mean? Also, when I execute `ruby -v`, it lists my version as 1.9.3p0 but this is dicking around in 1.9.1? All I want is my irb back and working!

Comment: What OS? Why aren't you using RVM?

Comment: Who forced you to upgrade?  You could have used 1.8.7 or wrritten your own Float.round.

Comment: @MarkThomas OS X. I am using RVM, and when I `rvm install 1.9.3` it says I already have. I tried reinstalling it, which was successful. `ruby -v` says I'm on 1.9.3, but irb is looking in `.../ruby/1.9.1` and I don't know why

Comment: @DavidGrayson I could have, yes, but I wasn't expecting a stable release to fail so spectacularly. Having a simple class (round) in a basic class (Float) didn't inspire much confidence to stick around

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that Ruby was looking for an XML parser called 'crack'. I don't know why it is referencing 2 versions of Ruby or why these dependencies aren't included in the Ruby build (since irb won't work without them) but to fix I installed the crack gem. `sudo gem install crack`

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
require_relative 'Location.rb'
```

or

```
require './Location.rb'
```

Comment: in a file yes, but not in irb. That also won't fix the LoadError about crack

Comment: or you can use it as require 'XXXlib/Location.rb' I dont know which library you are using. take look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632090/how-can-i-reload-a-script-in-irb

Comment: not a library, just testing scripts that are all in a folder together

Comment: what about "require './Location.rb'"

Comment: Yeah that works, as does require_relative, but it is still such a pain to have to add ./ to the load path.