# Reload rubygems in irb?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb

I've this script right now.

```
def r(this)
  require this
  puts "#{this} is now loaded."
rescue LoadError
  puts "The gem '#{this}' is missing."
  puts "Should I install it? [y/n]"
  data = gets
  if data =~ /yes|y/i
    puts "Installing #{this}, hold on."
    if `gem install #{this}` =~ /Successfully/i
      load this
    end
  else
    puts "Okey, goodbye."
  end
end
```

That makes it possible to require libs on the fly.
Like this: `r "haml"`.

The problem is that I can't load the gem after it has been installed.
Using `load this` or `load File.expand_path("~/.irbrc")` does not work.

Here is an example.

```
>> r "absolutize"
The gem 'absolutize' is missing.
Should I install it? [y/n]
y
Installing absolutize, hold on
LoadError: no such file to load -- absolutize
>> require "absolutize"
LoadError: no such file to load -- absolutize
>> exit
$ irb
>> require "absolutize"
=> true
```

Is there a way to reload rubygems or irb on the fly?

Comment: This question was answered before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463182/reload-rubygem-in-irb/3465637#3465637

Comment: I've already tried using that solution and it did not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did not try, but I think you might be looking for [`Gem.clear_paths`](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem.html#method-c-clear_paths)

> Reset the dir and path values. The next time dir or path is requested, the values will be calculated from scratch. This is mainly used by the unit tests to provide test isolation.

Comment: Thanks. [Here](https://gist.github.com/948109) is the final version of the script above.

Answer (score 3):

You can reset irb by calling `exec('irb')`

Comment: I've used `exec "irb -r #{this}"` before. The problem is that it will "unload" all of my gems. So if I for example did this. `require "random"; r "something"` then `random` won't be loaded after installing `something`.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463182/reload-rubygem-in-irb/3465637#3465637) might have what you're looking for then.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the file from ´$"´:

```
require 'erb' # Loaded.
require 'erb' # Does nothing.
$".delete_if {|e| e =~ /erb\.(?:rb|so)/} # Remove "erb" from loaded libraies.
require 'erb' # Reloaded (with warnings if the first require was successful).
```

See http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#19