# How to reload a gem in development into Pry/IRB

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, irb, pry

I am building a gem and am occasionally testing it in IRB by using the command: `bundle console`. It works fine, but is there a way to reload the gem without restarting the console? Also, I wish to do this in Pry. Any ideas for it?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463182/reload-rubygem-in-irb

Comment: It's a half duplicate.  irb and pry are different enough that this question could have different answers for them.  I would suggest this question be edited to be for pry only, and other remain for irb.

Comment: That solution in the claimed duplicate didn't solve my issue. Should I edit my question and explain that it didn't work?